# Java CompletableFuture.anyOf(manyfutures).thenRun( runnable ) only runs once

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8

I was doing

```
CompletableFuture.anyOf(manyfutures).thenRun( new Runnable() { } }
```

but the code in the runnable is only running once! I was expecting it to run many times, every time any of the futures completes.

How can I run a block of code everytime any of the futures completes? In optimal fashion, meaning this won't do:

```
    public static void append(final CompletableFuture[] futures, Runnable runnable) {
            for (CompletableFuture future : futures) {
                    future.thenRun(runnable);
            }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I am using a ThreadPoolExecutor which I want to append more work to when an X number of runnables have executed.

Is there a way to listen for this and supply more work when that happens?

The alternative is that I stack thousands of work in the beginning, but that is not optimal either.

I am doing

```
... queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(); 
new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
```

Comment: @Holger Well, I have a 1 million rows in the database which I fetch and do work with asynchronously. Rather than fetching 1 million rows, I fetch 500 and have 20 threads. Really, my question was more about finding out when those 20 threads have worked on 70% of the 500 to fetch more from the database but all threads are in reality busy all the time. I think my edit was a bit incorrectly formulated. Makes sense now? :) I have supplied my answer below.

Comment: That makes more sense. However, using an `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a well defined limit rather than an unlimited `LinkedBlockingQueue` would be the simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer for keeping track of this, this method takes a couple of parameters for convience:

```
   /** Basically creates to-start number of futures in a while loop, while passing the index to a Lambda that is passed and that returns a Runnable which will have access to the index. See example below. **/
   public static CompletableFuture[] async(ExecutorService executorService, int start, int to, Runnable beforeAll, Lambda.R1<Runnable, Integer> onEach, Double onPercentage, Runnable onPercentageRun, Runnable afterAll) {
            CompletableFuture[] futures = new CompletableFuture[to-start];

            double        onPercentageIndex = Valid.elvis(onPercentage, 0.0) * futures.length;  // When to onPercentageRun
            AtomicBoolean percentageMet     = new AtomicBoolean ( false );
            AtomicBoolean completeMet       = new AtomicBoolean ( false );
            AtomicInteger complete          = new AtomicInteger ( 0     );

            int i = start;
            if ( i < to && beforeAll != null ) {
                    beforeAll.run();
            }
            boolean percentageSet = onPercentageIndex > 0.0 && onPercentageRun != null;
            boolean completeSet = afterAll != null;
            while( i < to ) {

                    Runnable call = onEach.call(i);
                    futures[i-start] = CompletableFuture.runAsync(

                            () -> {
                                    try {
                                            call.run();
                                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                                            $Log.info(Concurrency.class, "RunAsync: run", e);
                                    }

                                    if ( percentageSet || completeSet ) {
                                            complete.incrementAndGet();

                                            if ( percentageSet && !percentageMet.get() && complete.get() >= onPercentageIndex) {
                                                    percentageMet.set(true);

                                                    try {
                                                            onPercentageRun.run();
                                                    }
                                                    catch(Throwable e) {
                                                            $Log.info(Concurrency.class, "RunAsync: onPercentage", e);
                                                    }
                                            }

                                            if ( completeSet && !completeMet.get() && complete.get() == to ) {
                                                    completeMet.set(true); // Just for clarity, propably redundant

                                                    try {
                                                            afterAll.run();
                                                    }
                                                    catch(Throwable e) {
                                                            $Log.info(Concurrency.class, "RunAsync: onComplete", e);
                                                    }

                                            }
                                    }

                            },

                            executorService
                    );

                    ++i;
            }

            return futures;
    }
```

For a reference to what Lambda.R1 is, see this, [Lambda interfaces](https://bitbucket.org/momomo/opensource/src/60813ef702bddcdda1bcde20820850b8cc5baa1a/src/momomo/com/Functional/lambdas/version/interfaces/Lambda.java?at=default)

The method can be used like this:

```
    private void recursivelyPopulateDataFiles(long fromId) {

            List<Localfile> unproccessed = DB.fetchAllFilesFromId(fromId, limit);

            if ( unproccessed.size() > 0 ) {

                    Concurrency.async(
                            THE_EXECUTOR,

                            0,

                            unproccessed.size(),

                            ITERATIONS_COUNTER_IN_PROGRESS_CAN_BE_USED_BY_OTHERS_TO_LISTEN_GLOBALLY_FOR_WHEN_IT_HITS_ZERO_AGAIN::incrementAndGet,

                            (Integer index) -> () -> {
                                    populateDataFile( unproccessed.get(index) );
                            },

                            0.5,

                            () -> {
                                    recursivelyPopulateDataFiles(unproccessed.get(unproccessed.size() - 1).getId());

                            },

                            ITERATIONS_COUNTER_IN_PROGRESS_CAN_BE_USED_BY_OTHERS_TO_LISTEN_GLOBALLY_FOR_WHEN_IT_HITS_ZERO_AGAIN::decrementAndGet
                    );

            }

    }
```

When 0.5 = 50% of the size of unproccessed are done, the block afterwards executes to place more on the executor.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#anyOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-)

> Returns a new `CompletableFuture` that is completed when any of the
>   given `CompletableFutures` complete, with the same result. Otherwise, if
>   it completed exceptionally, the returned `CompletableFuture` also does
>   so, with a `CompletionException` holding this exception as its cause. If
>   no `CompletableFutures` are provided, returns an incomplete
>   `CompletableFuture`.

The method returns when **any** of the given `CompletableFutures` complete. i.e. the first one. A method cannot return multiple times.

To run an action after *each* `CompletableFuture` just call `theRun` or `thenRunAsync` on *each* `CompletableFuture`.

If you have a `List<CompletableFuture<T>>` and you want a `CompletableFuture<List<T>>`, i.e. you want to "unwrap" a collection of futures into a future of a collection, you can use this trick:

```
private static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> sequence(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
    final CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));
    return allDoneFuture.thenApply(v ->
                    futures.stream().
                            map(future -> future.join()).
                            collect(toList())
    );
}
```

Taken from [this article on the usage of `CompletableFuture`](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-completablefuture)

Comment: Ok, I did and I also noticed this behaviour. How can I do what I intended then? Preferably in an optimal manner.

Comment: So I have to loop through then and append it. I was hoping not to have to do that. What I want is to run something when for instance 70% of them has completed.

Comment: You might be better off using an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.htmlhttps://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).

Comment: I am using a ThreadPoolExecutor which I want to append work to when it more than 70% of the allocated threads go idle. Is there a way to listen to this and supply more work when that happens? The alternative is that I stack thousands of work in the beginning, but that is not optimal either.

Comment: Why do you need that? Just supply a `BlockingQueue` to the `Executor`. Give it a smallish size (1000 or so). The supplying thread will block if the `Queue` is full.

Comment: I am not sure I am able to figure out how to work that. I am doing this: new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()); so I have a blocking queue. "The supplying thread will block".. but I am fetching data from the database. I can fetch 1000 or 1000 000 million at a time. If I supply a million to the queue, it doesn't sound ideal to me, even if it does block.

Comment: You have almost 2000 rep. You should know that posting unformatted code in a comment doesn't go down well. You should also know how to edit you question.

Comment: Sorry about that, but the flat nature of stackoverflow is not ideal. I asked the question, now it lead to someplace else.

Comment: Your edit uses allOf meaning all must complete. I am looking for when each and one of them completes, so that I can determine when 70% of them are done.

Comment: My edit was before your additional information completely changed the question. You don't limit the size of the queue in your code. If you stream the data from the database using a cursor then you won't read the whole lot into memory at the same time.

Comment: I think my question was quite clear from the beginning.